# JavaScript onclick Event when "id" does not exist

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Let me start off by saying my JavaScript skills are lacking, to say the least. I have been having a problem with the following function:

```
function setClickHandler(element) {
    element.onchange = function () {
        var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        if(document.getElementById(id) !== null){
            clickHandler = document.getElementById(id).onclick;
        } else {
            clickHandler ="runMe('" + this.id + "','" + id + "','','null')"; }
        clickHandler.apply(this);
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is if a element exists with the "id" then use that elements `onclick` function and if it doesn't exist then create the one within the function. Then apply this `onclick` function to the element.

Everything works except if the "id" does not exist and it goes into the else statement where the `clickHandler` has to be created. I cannot figure out why this won't work. I did notice when I logged it if `clickHandler` was taken from another existing id then `clickHandler` output something like `(onclick).event` where if it went into the else statement it output `runMe('24','54','','null')`.

I hope I am explaining this well enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the else statement never firing?

Comment: @JSager, it will fire properly , it's just that created onclick event will not be applied to the element.

Comment: Is "runMe" a function you declared somewhere, or are you trying to create it with the string?

Comment: @NiklasRingdahi, I am trying to create it with the string

Comment: actually, it is a function i have created elsewhere, I am just trying to call that function on an onclick and send those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're creating a string in the else case, which you can't call as a function. try this

```
if (document.getElementById(id) !== null) {
    clickHandler = document.getElementById(id).onclick;
    clickHandler.apply(this);
}
else {
    // clickHandler = "runMe('" + this.id + "','" + id + "','','null')";
    var runMeArgs = [this.id, id, '', 'null'];
    runMe.apply(this, runMeArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In one case you're setting `clickHandler` to a function, in the other case you're setting it to a string?

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else {
   var me = this;
   clickHandler = function() {
      runMe(me.id, id, '', null);
   }
}
...
```

Possibly.

Comment: This is close but the scope for `runMe` will not be the same as OP's code would indicate. you need to end up with the equivalent of `runMe.apply(this)` while maintaining arguments.